# SSH: ProxyJump still requires password

Tags: ssh, networking, ssh-tunneling

I used to connect to a remote server (e.g., `userT@target.example`) through a bastion machine (e.g., `userG@gateway.example`) using the following command from my local machine:

```
ssh userT@target.example
```

The above command does not require the password, as I have set up SSH keys for the connections (`local --> bastion, bastion --> target`), in addition to the following configuration in the `~/.ssh/config` of my local machine:

```
Host target.example
    Match User userT
        ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' userG@gateway.example 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
```

Recently, the administrator of `target.example` has observed that I caused a lot (hundreds) of non-closed connections. I was then recommended to use ProxyJump instead:

```
Host target.example
    Match User userT
        ProxyJump userG@gateway.example
```

This command worked at first, but after a restart of my local machine, each connection requires me to enter the password for `userT@target.example`. As a workaround, I do this each time I restart my machine:

1. Change the `ProxyJump` line in `~/.ssh/config` to the `ProxyCommand` line.
2. `ssh userT@target.example`.
3. Change the `ProxyCommand` line in `~/.ssh/config` back to `ProxyJump`.

The above is highly inconvenient. Therefore, I would like to know if there is a way to make `ProxyJump` works correctly (i.e., allowing me to connect to `target.example` without typing any password. (Just in case: The version of OpenSSH on my bastion machine is 6.0, while ProxyJump requires >= 7.3, I am not sure if this is the root cause of the issue.)

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

**Update:**

I tried adding `ForwardAgent` to `~/.ssh/config` as suggested by @Wieland:

```
Host gateway.example
    ForwardAgent yes
Host target.example
    Match User userT
        ProxyJump userG@gateway.example
```

but the issue remains.

Comment: I don't have an environment to reproduce this in, but you seem to be no longer forwarding your SSH agent to the jump host in your new configuration. Can you try adding `Host gateway.example\nForwardAgent yes` to your SSH config file?

Comment: @Wieland Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem. Please see the update part of the question.

Comment: @Wieland It turns out that I have to add the SSH public key of my local machine to `target.example` as well when using `ProxyJump`. Now everything is working.

Answer (score 3):

For ProxyJump to work, it suffices to add the SSH public key of my local machine to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of `target.example`.

Previously I had only added the key of the local machine to `gateway.example` (and of course the key of `gateway` to `target.example` as well), but it turns out that this is not sufficient for ProxyJump.