# ProxyJump in login->compute node still requires password

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, key-authentication

I want to ssh from LAPTOP to COMPUTE but have to go through LOGIN, and COMPUTE and LOGIN share users (so no separate ssh configs).

This question is similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/635408/ssh-proxyjump-still-requires-password) with the exception that in my case my servers are of a login/compute set-up.  So the user accounts/user directories are the same across the bastion (login) and the target (compute node). LAPTOP cannot directly ssh into COMPUTE but has to go through LOGIN.

```
LAPTOP --> [LOGIN --> COMPUTE]
|                        ^
+------------ X ---------+
```

On `LAPTOP` (Windows) I have the following .ssh/config:

```
Host loginnode
    HostName login.company.org
    User bramvanroy
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mycompanykey

Host computenode
    HostName compute.company.org
    User bramvanroy
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mycompanykey
    ProxyJump loginnode
```

On `LOGIN`, there is its own config that looks like this:

```
Host computenode
    HostName compute
    User bramvanroy
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Permissions:

- `authorized_keys`: 600
- `config`: 644

While I can indeed ssh from LAPTOP into LOGIN without a password (`ssh loginnode`), when I try `ssh computenode`, I am still asked for a password.

Why is that and how can I solve that?

Again, I cannot use intermediate SSH keys between LOGIN/COMPUTE as far as I understand, because they both use the same accounts and configs.

---

Output of `ssh -vvv computenode` (real names/ip addresses are different):

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data config
debug1: config line 31: Applying options for computenode
debug3: Failed to open file:ssh_config error:2
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: "C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe"  -vvv -W "[%h]:%p" loginnode
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec "C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe"  -vvv -W "[compute.company.org]:22" loginnode
debug3: spawning "C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe"  -vvv -W "[compute.company.org]:22" loginnode
debug3: w32_getpeername ERROR: not sock :2
debug3: Failed to open file:.ssh/loginnode.pub error:2
debug1: identity file loginnode type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:.ssh/loginnode-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:.ssh/loginnode-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file loginnode-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data config
debug1: config line 26: Applying options for loginnode
debug3: Failed to open file:ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "login.company.org" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to loginnode REDACTED port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:.ssh/loginnode.pub error:2
debug1: identity file loginnode type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:.ssh/loginnode-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:.ssh/loginnode-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file loginnode-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to login.company.org:22 as 'bramvanroy'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from login.company.org
debug3: Failed to open file:.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: REDACTED
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from login.company.org
debug3: Failed to open file:.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from REDACTED
debug3: Failed to open file:.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'login.company.org' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in known_hosts:6
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: loginnode  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: loginnode
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: REDACTED
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to login.company.org (REDACTED:22).
debug3: ssh_init_stdio_forwarding: compute.company.org:22
debug1: channel_connect_stdio_fwd compute.company.org:22
debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: w32_getsockname ERROR: bad fd: -1
debug3: w32_getpeername ERROR: bad fd: -1
debug3: w32_getpeername ERROR: bad fd: -1
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to compute.company.org:22 as 'bramvanroy'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from compute.company.org
debug3: Failed to open file:.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: REDACTED
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from compute.company.org
debug3: Failed to open file:.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'compute.company.org' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in known_hosts:9
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: loginnode  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: loginnode
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: REDACTED
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Hard to tell, more data needed -- try running `ssh -v computenode` and see what it *actually does* during the proxy jump and handshake phases. **NOTE** this will contain a *lot* of output that's a potential security risk, so make sure to curate/censor the output.

Comment: @Shadur Thanks for the reply. I have added the output of `ssh -vvv` and tried to redact/anonymize as well as I thought necessary. Let me know if something is out of place. Thanks

Comment: Be aware that `ProxyJump loginnode` does not mean `ssh computenode` first connects to LOGIN from LAPTOP and then automatically `ssh computenode` from LOGIN. It first connects to LOGIN from LAPTOP and then automatically connects to COMPUTE *from LAPTOP, using packets tunneled via LOGIN*. No `ssh` process is run on LOGIN and therefore the SSH config, credentials (keys) or availability of agent on LOGIN don't matter at all. So e.g. "does the SSH server on LOGIN permit agent forwarding?" is irrelevant. From the log it seems the key-based authentication succeeded for LOGIN, but not for COMPUTE.

Comment: Are you able to check logs from `sshd` on COMPUTE? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61289603/10765659) and links therein may help.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski My sysadmin tells me that AllowAgentForwarding is enabled but also notes that `OpenSSH 7.4p1` is being used (RHEL 7). Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: My comment was exactly to let you know that agent forwarding is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sysadmin lets me know that the issue was that `COMPUTE` did not have the SELinux parameter `use_nfs_home_dirs` enabled. After enabling that, everything works as intended now.

Answer (score 0):

From that data dump, the key issue that springs out is:

```
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: loginnode  explicit
```

It tries to connect back to your SSH agent but the socket doesn't appear to exist.

Are you sure the agent is running?

Comment: Do you mean the SSH agent on LAPTOP? Yes, it is. I can easily connect to `LOGIN`. The issue is that when I try to connect to `COMPUTE` it asks me for my password (not using the public key). When I enter the password I can enter without issue, but that defeats the purpose of having a key. So I want to be able to just effortlessly login with my public key by  tunneling through `LOGIN` into `COMPUTE` using the same key, basically.

Comment: I have now made sure that the OpenSSH Authentication Agent is enabled in Windows services and while that solves the "unable to connect" error, the same issue persists (still have to enter password). The only relevant debug message seems "debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method" but no reason is given.

Comment: Does the SSH server on `LOGIN` permit agent forwarding?

Comment: My sysadmin tells me that AllowAgentForwarding is enabled but also notes that `OpenSSH 7.4p1` is being used (RHEL 7). Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Try ssh-ing to the `LOGIN` server and then running `ssh-add -l`. Add the output to your question, it may be relevant.

Comment: This is the output `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`.

Comment: Your agent isn't enabled, or SSH agent forwarding isn't enabled, or the SSH daemon on `LOGIN` does not permit agent forwarding.

Comment: Thank you, but is that an issue? According to KamilMaciorowski in the comments, port forwarding is not a problem. So no authentication happens from LOGIN to COMPUTE as far as I understand it?

Comment: SSH agent forwarding is what your SSH client uses to chain authentications, whether you proxy jump or hop manually. If it's not enabled then no, you won't be able to log on to `COMPUTE` using your ssh key.

Comment: So I finally started the ssh-agent, added the private key, and still the same problem occurs (still need to enter a password to get to the COMPUTE node). I do not see much difference in the verbose output, still just `debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method`.

Comment: It was an issue on the COMPUTE side, see my answer.